# Location of "assets" (php, css, jss, ect)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

In my root directory I have a bunch of single pages and then the folder "blog" and "assets." For the pages I have a header.php/nav.php/footer.php to call for various css and js.

for example: within the header.php:

```
<link href="http://beta.rfahaiti.org/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, in the pages I call for:  `<?php include 'assets/header.php'; ?>`

However, this does not seem to be working for any pages within the blog folder -- such as the index.php file in /blog/news/. I assume it's a relative vs absolute link issue but I'm not sure how to fix. Question: what does the php include call need to be for to call for the header.php file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php include '../assets/header.php'; ?>
```

or

```
<?php include '../../assets/header.php'; ?>
```

depending on your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Include paths are relative, try:

```
<?php include '../assets/header.php'; ?>
```

You will find the same with HTML document referring to resources e.g CSS.

Comment: Yes, that's odd. I'm not able to do that yet since it requires 125 reputation. Are you able to see who gave you negative feedback?

Comment: Don't think so, I gave the other two guys +1

Answer (score 0):

It is a relative link issue, as you say.  For pages two levels deep in /blog/news, you need to go two levels back:

```
../../assets/header.php
```

**Edit** thanks to Juan Sosa for pointing out that what follows is completely wrong.

<s>Alternatively, you could write this:</s>

```
/assets/header.php
```

The second approach is cleaner in one sense; however, beware it assumes that your site will always be located at the root of the domain (ie, if it ever got moved to `http://beta.rfahaiti.org/theapplication/` or something, then all those type of links would break).

Comment: Including '/assets/header.php' (with a starting slash) will look for the header.php file in the root folder /, which is not what is being asked.

Comment: @JuanSosa I don't understand what you're saying -- how is pointing to the root not one possible answer to this question?

Comment: Sorry for my english. If the file path in the include sentence has a starting slash like in your second code sample it will be an "absolute path" and php will look for the file in the root folder (i.e. C:\assets\ in windows, or /assets/ in linux and mac), which is not what the OP wants. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Juan. His first solution works great and the second doesn't work like you noted.

Comment: @JuanSosa thanks, you're right.  I had no idea ... I'm a bit of a PHP noob, and that is very different than how ASP.Net behaves.